# Trouble with L'Hopitals rule when calculating $\lim_{x\to2\pm\sqrt3}\frac{e^{-x}}{-x^2+4x-1}$

Tags: limits

I was asked to find the limit of $$\frac{e^{-x}}{-x^2+4x-1}$$ as $x$ tends to $2 + \sqrt{3}$ and $2 - \sqrt{3}$.

I tried to use L'Hôpital's rule as the denominator would otherwise be $0$. After differentiating twice, I got $\frac{e^{-x}}{-2}$. However, when I take the limits, I get a value, which is incorrect as I can see from the graph of the function that the limit is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong here. Thank you!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is only allowable when the limit of the numerator *and* denominator of a fraction are zero. In this problem, the numerator has a finite, nonzero limit at both points.

Comment: It is not an indeterminate form, you don't need l'Hospital and, in general, l'Hospital is not a good way to solve such kind of limits.

Comment: Compare with limit of $\frac 1 x$ as $x \to 0+$. You cannot apply L'Hopital's Rule in such cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [L'Hopital's rule for $\frac{e^{x}}{1-e^{x}}$ for$ x\to 0, \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008289/lhopitals-rule-for-fracex1-ex-for-x-to-0-infty)

Comment: It suffices to observe that $e^{-x} \to a>0$ and $-x^2+4x-1 \to 0^+$ for $x \to (2 - \sqrt{3})^+$ and for $x \to (2 + \sqrt{3})^-$, while $-x^2+4x-1 \to 0^-$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. You're basically saying, *my eyes tell me one thing (from the graph), but L'Hopital's rule tells me another. What am I missing?*

The answer, as I said in my comment, is that you're missing one of the hypotheses of L'Hopital's rule. It is not sufficient that the denominator tend to zero; both the numerator and denominator must tend to zero in order to substitute the limit of the quotient of the derivatives. So L'Hopital is out of the question here.

The graph shows you that there are vertical asymptotes at the two zeros of the denominator, with limits of $\pm\infty$ on each side. To verify this rigorously, it's hard to find the right balance between manual dexterity (i.e., hand waving), and epsilon-delta. As an instructor, I would be looking for something like this: As $x\to (2-\sqrt{3})^-$, the numerator tends to a positive number, while the denominator tends to zero but remains positive. So the limit from the left is $+\infty$. And so on.